# In django, bulk_create with update_conflicts=True doesn't work if I have multiple UniqueConstraints

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have this model:

```
class XYZ(Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    keys_1 = models.IntegerField()
    keys_2 = models.JSONField(null=False, default=dict)
    keys_3 = models.DateField(null=True, default=None)
    values = models.JSONField(null=False, default=dict)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "xyz"

        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["keys_1", "keys_2"],
                name="unicity_when_keys_3_null",
                condition=Q(keys_3__isnull=True),
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["keys_1", "keys_2", "keys_3"],
                name="unicity",
            ),
        ]
```

I then do this:

```
XYZ.objects.bulk_create(
        data,
        update_conflicts=True,
        unique_fields=["keys_1", "keys_2", "keys_3"],
        update_fields=["values"],
)
```

with `data` being a list of `XYZ` objects

- If `data[n].keys_3` is not `None`, it works as expected
- **If `data[n].keys_3` is `None`, it fails on conflict, citing the `unicity_when_keys_3_null` constraint**

Am I doing something wrong ?

PS:

- these can't be used

```
XYZ.objects.bulk_create(
        data,
        update_conflicts=True,
        unique_fields=["keys_1", "keys_2"],
        update_fields=["values"],
)

XYZ.objects.bulk_create(
        data,
        update_conflicts=True,
        unique_fields=["keys_1", "keys_2"],
        update_fields=["values", "keys_3"],
)
```

- this doesn't work

```
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["keys_1", "keys_2"],
                name="unicity_when_keys_3_null",
                condition=Q(keys_3__isnull=True),
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["keys_1", "keys_2", "keys_3"],
                name="unicity",
                condition=Q(keys_3__isnull=False),
            ),
        ]
```

- a functioning workaround is :

```
        for row in data: # here data is a list of dicts
            ProductDataSourceValues.objects.update_or_create(
                key_1=row["key_1"],
                key_2=row["key_2"],
                key_3=row["key_3"],
                defaults={"values": row["values"]},
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model:**

```
class XYZ(Model):
        id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
        keys_1 = models.IntegerField()
        keys_2 = models.JSONField(null=False, default=dict)
        keys_3 = models.DateField(null=True, default=None)
        values = models.JSONField(null=False, default=dict)
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = "xyz"
    
            constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=["keys_1", "keys_2", "keys_3"],
                    name="unicity",
                ),
                models.UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=["keys_1", "keys_2"],
                    name="unicity_when_keys_3_null",
                    condition=Q(keys_3__isnull=True),
                ),
            ]
```

**To create new objects and update conflicts:**

```
    XYZ.objects.bulk_create(
        data,
        update_conflicts=True,
        unique_fields=["keys_1", "keys_2", "keys_3"],
        update_fields=["values"],
    )
```

Comment: AFAIU what you're suggesting is exactly what I tried, except for the order of the constraints ?

Comment: `models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["keys_1", "keys_2", "keys_3"],name="unicity",),`   You added as constraint?

Comment: yes, see my first code snippet

Comment: There is difference between your model and my model I can see. Please use my full model there. It should work.

Comment: i'm gonna try but the only difference I see is the order of UniqueConstraints in constraints ...

Comment: ok so I tried with your solution and it doesn't work either, because the only difference i see is the order of the constraints, which doesn't matter. Please point me to another difference in your code, because I can't see it

Comment: This answer is just a replica of the question and does not answer the question asked...